# Inifinite loop in bash

Tags: bash

I have written the following command to loop over a set of strings in the second column of my file and then do sorting for each string on column 11, then take the second and eleventh column and count the number of unique occurrences. Very simple but it seems that it enters an infinite loop and I can't see why. I would appreciate your help very much.

```
for item in $(cat file.txt | cut -f2 -d " "| uniq)
do
   sort -k11,11 file.txt | cut -f2,11 -d " " | uniq -c | sort -k2,2 > output
done
```

Comment: You realize it's going to overwrite `output` from the beginning on every pass, destroying prior iterations? What's the point here?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Could you provide some sample input and desired output? It looks to me that you are using a lot of pipes for something that should be more straight forward.

Comment: Doesn't look like an infinite loop to me.  The `for item in $(...)` part is only calculated once, so that won't be the issue.  Try enabling xtrace with `set -o xtrace` then run the command.  It will show you each command as it runs it.

Comment: what's your `item` for? why it's not used?

Comment: just run you script as `bash -x script_name` and will see yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no infinite loop here, but it *is* a very silly loop (that takes a long time to run, while not accomplishing the script's stated purpose). Let's look at how one might accomplish that purpose more sanely:

---

Using a temporary file for `counts.txt` to avoid needing to rerun the `sort`, `cut` and `uniq` steps on each iteration:

```
sort -k11,11 file.txt | cut -f2,11 -d " " | uniq -c >counts.txt
while read -r item; do
   fgrep -e " ${item}" counts.txt
done < <(cut -f2 -d' ' <file.txt | uniq)
```

Even better, using bash 4 associative arrays and no temporary file:

```
# reads counts into an array
declare -A counts=( )
while read -r count item; do
  counts[$item]=count
done < <(sort -k11,11 file.txt | cut -f2,11 -d " " | sort | uniq -c)

# reads counts back out
while read -r item; do
  echo "$item ${counts[$item]}"
done < <(cat file.txt | cut -f2 -d " "| sort | uniq)
```

...that said, that's only if you want to use `sort` for ordering on pulling data back out. If you don't need to do that, the latter part could be replaced as such:

```
# read counts back out
for item in "${!counts[@]}"; do
  echo "$item ${counts[$item]}"
done
```